# How can I initialize the Firebase Admin SDK in spring-boot application using kotlin

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, kotlin, firebase-admin

I would like to get data from Firebase. I found some tutorials, but all is using Google Credential ServiceAccount to initialize firebase app. this's is tutorial that i found :
https://medium.com/techwasti/spring-boot-firebase-crud-b0afab27b26e , and else tutorial i found, almost like that too, is using ServiceAccount.

But the problem is i cannot get the ServiceAccount from this firebase because it's from third party. that's mean the owner of firebase don't want to give ServiceAccount.json to me, but they give me firebase config to me, like this :

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "apkey",
  authDomain: authdomain",
  databaseURL: "databaseurl",
  projectId: "projectid",
  storageBucket: "storragebucket",
  messagingSenderId: "messagesenderid",
  appId: "appid",
  measurementId: "measurementid"
};
```

So, how can i initialize this firebase using kotlin in my java springboot aplication?

i had try to find the solution, but not found anything,
I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to initialize the Firebase Admin SDK, you will need a service account.  There are no alternatives for this.

The config for the front end web app that you're showing here will not work at all.  That config is only used for frontend apps that are acting as clients on behalf of the end user.

Comment: Thanks for respon, i think so... hmmm i will try to initialize using frontend apps, thanks again